# java.io.FileNotFoundException for text file

Tags: android, filereader

I have a txt file in the root folder of my Android project called KARIN.txt. I am trying to reach it by `FileReader`  but I am having the following error:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /KARIN.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

How I am trying to reach that file is as following:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("KARIN.txt"));
```

I am confused that why it is not allowing me to read the file.

Comment: Probably because there is no file in that exact location, did you already check that?

Comment: you can't write on `/` . Only root can write on `/`

Comment: Try to specify the absolute path.

Comment: *root folder of my Android project*. Is it on your pc?

Comment: what if I put the KARIN.txt to texts folder. How should I call it with FileReader?

Comment: If you need it in runtime, move the file to source/resource folders. Project root folder is not bundled with your application.

Comment: @blackbelt Im running the project on real device.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If KARIN.txt is built into your project you should put it in the assets folder and access it via the AssetManager.

```
public String loadFile(String file){
        AssetManager am = getActivity().getAssets();
        InputStreamReader ims = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        String data = "File not available!";
        try {
            ims = new InputStreamReader(am.open(file), "UTF-8");
            reader = new BufferedReader(ims);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if(ims != null){
            try {
                String mLine = reader.readLine();
                data = "";
                while(mLine != null){
                    data+= mLine;
                    mLine = reader.readLine();
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally{
                if (reader != null) {
                     try {
                         reader.close();
                     } catch (IOException e) {
                         e.printStackTrace();
                     }
                }
            }
        }
        return data;
}
```

Comment: Eclipse underlines getActivity to red.

Comment: Ah, Sorry this was my code from another fragment. in this case ignore getActivity() and just use `getAssets()`